# Gson and abstract superclasses: deserialization issue

Tags: java, gson

Suppose to have an **abstract** class, say `A`, and two non-abstract subclasses, say `A1` and `A2`. I want to "deserialize" them from a json format by using the [GSON library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

E.g. I get an array of `A` objects.

```
int n = ...;
A[] list = new A[n];
A[0] = new A1(....);
A[1] = new A2(....);
...
```

which someone converted to a JSON string as follows:

```
String json = (new Gson()).toJson(list);
```

Finally, if I try to deserialize as follows

```
A[] deserializedList =  (new Gson()).fromJson(json, A[].class);
```

then I has got an error, since the GSON default deserializer finds an abstract class (i.e. `A`) and it is not capable of guessing the subclass type.

How can I solve this?

PS: I read about custom deserializer, but I don't understand how to use them in this case.

Comment: Take a look at this http://ovaraksin.blogspot.com.es/2011/05/json-with-gson-and-abstract-classes.html

Comment: @Axxiss Oh! Ok, so I can't use a simple list, I have to save the object class type in the serialized string. Mhhh! It would be better if the GSON guys will add a method to enabled the auto saving of the class type property!

Comment: Well, please, post an asnwer related to this question so that I can accept it!

Comment: Well,currently I don't have the time to give a better answer. Probably you should create an answer by yourself taking the link as a starting point ;)

Comment: @Axxiss Of course, I'm going to do this. My aim was to accept your answer in order to give the points to you!

Comment: After trying the explicit class name like A[] deserializedList =  (new Gson()).fromJson(json, A1.class); did u get any error? @mat_boy

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Following the [Axxiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872492/gson-and-abstract-superclasses-deserialization-issue#comment24339445_16872492) link, here follows the answer. A custom serializer/deserializer must be provided.

```
public class AClassAdapter  implements JsonSerializer<A>, JsonDeserializer<A> {
  @Override
  public JsonElement serialize(A src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
      JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
      result.add("type", new JsonPrimitive(src.getClass().getSimpleName()));
      result.add("properties", context.serialize(src, src.getClass())); 
      return result;
  }


  @Override
  public A deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
        throws JsonParseException {
    JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
    String type = jsonObject.get("type").getAsString();
    JsonElement element = jsonObject.get("properties");

    try {            
        String fullName = typeOfT.getTypeName();
        String packageText = fullName.substring(0, fullName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        return context.deserialize(element, Class.forName(packageText + type));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        throw new JsonParseException("Unknown element type: " + type, cnfe);
    }
  }
}
```

Then the serialization is done like follows:

```
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
gson.registerTypeAdapter(A.class, new ATypeAdapter());
String json = gson.create().toJson(list);
```

and given the json string, the deserialization is:

```
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
gson.registerTypeAdapter(A.class, new ATypeAdapter());

return gson.create().fromJson(json, A[].class);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for a client. Nice.